# Permission denied with sudo

Tags: root, sudo, raspberry-pi2, buildroot

in a buildroot environment I added one user to the group wheel. Now I can execute commands with the root's privileges using sudo.

It seems it works but when I try to export a pin on my RPi I always get Permission denied:

```
rpi:~$ sudo echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export
sh: can't create /sys/class/gpio/export: Permission denied
```

Here the contents of that directory:

```
rpi:~$ ls -l /sys/class/gpio/
total 0
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Jan  1 00:00 export
lrwxrwxrwx    1 root     root             0 Jan  1 00:00 gpiochip0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/3f200000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip0
--w-------    1 root     root          4096 Jan  1 00:00 unexport
```

Isn't enough to get the root's privilege with sudo to write in the export file? I'm afraid about the owner and groups. In fact if I type:

```
rpi:~$ sudo chmod a+w /sys/class/gpio/*
```

then I can successfully export the pin. But I don't know if this is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you run the command `sudo echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export`, it first executes `sudo echo 4` which runs `echo` with elevated privileges (which is kind of pointless). Then the result is passed by the shell (not by `echo`) to a new command of `/sys/class/gpio/export`, which because it is a new command it isn't executed with elevated privileges.

There is a Unix.SE question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-do-you-process-an-entire-command-as-sudo-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping) which explains this and the options.

In summary of that link you should be able to do something like:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 4 > /sys/class/gpio/export'
```