# how to blink an LED using a PWM pin on Debian with C

Tags: c, linux, riscv, pwm

I have a VisionFive 2 SBC with Debian and I want to blink an LED attached to GPIO46 PWM0 pin using the Linux PWM library with a C program.

The goal is to modify an old existing program from a Raspberry Pi 3 using the wiringPi library and rewrite the PWM interface code to use a similar library to exercise the PWM interfaces.

What I'm hoping for is something that is simple and straightforward similar to the wiringPi library example below with a set of function calls to set up the PWM pin with a duty cycle, etc. and then let it run.

In case you're curious, this is the article I've written about my experience with the VisionFive 2 thus far, [Setting Up a New VisionFive 2 RISC-V SBC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372327/Setting-Up-a-New-VisionFive-2-RISC-V-SBC).

I have found a couple of SO postings that are not much help as they are more about Linux kernel development rather than a user space application.

- [Example of use pwm_get() in linux kernel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41268534/example-of-use-pwm-get-in-linux-kernel)
- [rpi - pwm_get() - how to use static lookup tables or device-tree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56155024/rpi-pwm-get-how-to-use-static-lookup-tables-or-device-tree)

This board does have a bit of instability however I've already implemented a blinking LED connected to a GPIO pin using the standard libgpiod library with a C program to control the GPIO pin. The PWM functionality is not available through libgpiod and appears to have its own library.

I found a few man pages such as this one [pwm_get](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/linux-manual-4.8/pwm_get.9.en.html) however I'm not sure how to use this function. It appears to be looking for some kind of a descriptor or identifier from the Linux device tree.

I found what looks to be the configuration file, `/boot/config-5.15.0-starfive`, which contains the following directives:

```
CONFIG_PWM=y
CONFIG_PWM_SYSFS=y
   ... a bunch of CONFIG_PWM_ directives commented out
CONFIG_PWM_STARFIVE_PTC=y
```

This documentation [JH7110 PWM Developing Guide](https://doc-en.rvspace.org/VisionFive2/Developer_Guide/SDK_DG_PWM.pdf) has this bit of code from some kind of a configuration or description file:

> For example, the pin configuration of PWM on the VisionFive 2 SBC is
> listed under the pwm_pins node in the file jh7110-visionfive-v2.dtsi.
>
> The following code block provides an example of the pins used by PWM
> including dout (Data Output), doen (Data Output Enable), and so on.

```
pwm_pins: pwm-pins {
 pwm_ch0-pins {
 sf,pins = <PAD_GPIO46>;
 sf,pinmux = <PAD_GPIO46_FUNC_SEL 0>;
 sf,pin-ioconfig = <IO(GPIO_IE(1))>;
 sf,pin-gpio-dout = <GPO_PTC0_PWM_0>;
 sf,pin-gpio-doen = <OEN_PTC0_PWM_0_OE_N>;
 };
 pwm_ch1-pins {
 sf,pins = <PAD_GPIO59>;
 sf,pinmux = <PAD_GPIO59_FUNC_SEL 0>;
 sf,pin-ioconfig = <IO(GPIO_IE(1))>;
 sf,pin-gpio-dout = <GPO_PTC0_PWM_1>;
 sf,pin-gpio-doen = <OEN_PTC0_PWM_1_OE_N>;
 };
};
```

In a later section, "4.1 Sysfs Interface Example", there is an example of accessing the PWM drivers through the Sysfs interface in `/sys/class/pwm/`. When I attempted to use the procedure as described, it did not work displaying an error message of `-bash: export: Permission denied`.

```
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm$ ls -l pwmchip0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Dec 31  2000 pwmchip0 -> ../../devices/platform/soc/120                                       d0000.pwm/pwm/pwmchip0
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm$ sudo echo 0 > export
-bash: export: Permission denied
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm$ cd pwmchip0
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$ ls
device  export  npwm  power  subsystem  uevent  unexport
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$ sudo echo 0 > export
-bash: export: Permission denied
```

Then I discovered this SO post, [Permission denied with sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452189/permission-denied-with-sudo), which explained the problem and the work around needed.

```
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$ sudo sh -c 'echo 0 > export'
[sudo] password for user:
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$ ls -l
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Nov 13 23:41 device -> ../../../120d0000.pwm
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 13 23:44 export
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Nov 13 23:41 npwm
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Nov 13 23:41 power
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root    0 Nov 13 23:44 pwm0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root    0 Dec 31  2000 subsystem -> ../../../../../../class/pwm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4096 Dec 31  2000 uevent
--w------- 1 root root 4096 Nov 13 23:41 unexport
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$ ls pwm0
capture  duty_cycle  enable  period  polarity  power  uevent
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0$
```

With the PWM device exported and usable, I was then able to drive a blinking LED using the Sysfs interface to the PWM drivers with the following settings which indicates the VisionFive 2 does have function PWM drivers in the Debian OS build.

```
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1 >enable'
[sudo] password for user:
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0$ sudo sh -c 'echo 1000000000 >period'
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0$ sudo sh -c 'echo 50000000 >duty_cycle'
user@starfive:/sys/class/pwm/pwmchip0/pwm0$ sudo sh -c 'echo 0 >enable'
```

The existing wiringPi library code is as follows:

```
/*
 *   This test program performs a test of a simple LED circuit
 *   that is connected to GPIO #18 to exercise the PWM by changing
 *   the brightness of an LED.
 *
 *   WARNING: running this program must be done with sudo in order for
 *            the wiringPi library to allow access to the PWM functionality
 *            of GPIO #18.
 *
 *   Compile with the following command line:
 *     cc pwmtest.c -lwiringPi
 *
 *   This command line compiles this test program and links it with the
 *   wiringPi.lib library for manipulating the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi.
*/

#include <wiringPi.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main ()
{
        // LEDPIN is wiringPi Pin #1 or GPIO #18
    // we choose this pin since it supports PWM as
    // PWM is not supported by any other GPIO pins.
        const int LEDPIN = 1;

    if (wiringPiSetup() == -1) {
        printf ("Setup wiringPi Failed!\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf ("Reminder: this program must be run with sudo. Delay 5 seconds.\n");
    delay (5000);
    printf ("   starting now.\n");
    pinMode (LEDPIN, PWM_OUTPUT);
    // set the PWM mode to Mark Space
    pwmSetMode(PWM_MODE_MS);
    // set the clock divisor to reduce the 19.2 Mhz clock
    // to something slower, 5 Khz.
    // Range of pwmSetClock() is 2 to 4095.
    pwmSetClock (3840);  // 19.2 Mhz divided by 3840 is 5 Khz.

    // set the PWM range which is the value for the range counter
    // which is decremented at the modified clock frequency.
    // in this case we are decrementing the range counter 5,000
    // times per second since the clock at 19.2 Mhz is being 
    // divided by 3840 to give us 5 Khz.
    pwmSetRange (2500);  // range is 2500 counts to give us half second.

    delay (1);   // delay a moment to let hardware settings settle.

    {
        int i;
        int list[] = {50, 500, 1024, 2500, -1};

        for (i = 0; list[i] > 0; i++) {
            // range for the value written is 0 to 1024.
            pwmWrite (LEDPIN, list[i]);  // set the Duty Cycle for this range.
            // delay 10 seconds to watch the LED flash due to the PWM hardware.
            printf (" PWM Duty Cycle %d\n", list[i]);
            delay (10000);
        } 
    }

    // cleanup the environment. set each pin to low
    // and set the mode to INPUT. These steps make sure
    // the equipment is safe to manipulate and prevents
    // possible short and equipment damage from energized pin.
    pinMode(LEDPIN, INPUT);
    digitalWrite (LEDPIN, LOW);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Richard, I know nothing about the startfive, but PWM features are generally board/chip dependent. The chip will provide the feature and the board with define which of the GPIO pins are primary for that feature (or secondary), etc.. PWM is nothing but a clock (timer, generally in UP mode with roll to zero) and and interrupt that defines the tick when the pin goes high during the timer count. PWM provides an "average" power by switching the pin on/off at high-frequency. The PWM "duty-cycle" is the percentage of time the pin is one compared to the timer/clock count.

Comment: If you don't have a library for the starfive that provides PWM functions, then you will need to datasheet for the startfive that defines what register defines the timer that can be used by PWM and the registers that set the *On* and *Rollover* counts for the timer. E.g., Say your timer clock runs as 3MHz and you have a 16-bit timer. If you set the rollover count at `32k`, the signal will run at 91.5Hz.  If you set your PWM on count at `16k`` (50% duty-cycle), the pin is low/off from 0-16k then switches high/on from 16k-32k giving you a average power of 50%. (on at 0, 100% power, etc..)

Comment: Here is a good [Timer/PWM lab/tutorial](https://lectures.tik.ee.ethz.ch/es/labs/lab2_solution.pdf), though using a TI board, the timer/PWM concept is universal. The TI board library uses the terminology of CCR (count control registers) that hold the PWM On and Rollover counters. While PIs and others don't use that same verbiage, I find it descriptive of what is happening. You are just setting a counter to control when ON happens for the pin happens and a count for when timer Rollover happens that defines the PWM for you. (then just connect the PWM pin as input to the LED output pin)

Comment: Found it! You need the [Starfive 2 - Developing and Porting Guide](https://www.starfivetech.com/uploads/VisionFive%202%20isionDocumentation.pdf) and specifically the [PWM Guide](https://doc-en.rvspace.org/VisionFive2/Developer_Guide/SDK_DG_PWM.pdf) -- and yes, it is pretty cheezy, but at least gives the hardware details. Also the [GPIO Guide](https://doc-en.rvspace.org/VisionFive2/Developer_Guide/SDK_DG_GPIO.pdf) I guess documentation isn't the Starfive's strong suit... There is a `starfive-tech` repo on github that contains some info as well.

Comment: [StarFive VisionFive 2 - sizeof cat](https://sizeof.cat/post/starfive-visionfive-2/) also looks good.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much for your comments. You have given me a great leg up on this. Now I just have to spend some time and work with it. I did find this YouTube video [Let's code a Linux Driver - 6: PWM Driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLm4EDVNceo) which is using some of the same functions mentioned in the PWM Guide you found. I don't really know anything about the linux kernel or device trees or modifying and building a kernel. It is on my list of things to learn though. I've set up the RISC-V toolchain on WSL and did a simple HelloWorld app that worked on the VisionFive.

Comment: It's actually pretty cool they provide hardware interface though `/dev`. That will make things soooo much easier than archaic registers, etc.. Basically, when configured, I get that the needed nodes will be created in `/dev` that you get to interface with to set the CCR values, etc.. I like playing with those little boards. I've done a couple of TI boards, the PI and Pico and PIco-w. Thoroughly enjoyed each (but did almost pull my hair out trying to figure them out -- but hey, if it wasn't a challenge, it wouldn't be any fun `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin The video author also has [Let's code a Linux Driver - 4: GPIO driver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P3Judr4i7QI) and it looks like he is using the same functions as described in [VisionFive 2 - Software SDK Developer Guide for
GPIO](https://doc-en.rvspace.org/VisionFive2/Developer_Guide/SDK_DG_GPIO.pdf) rather than the `libgpiod` library which does come with the VisionFive 2 Debian image and is what I've experimented with for GPIO control.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you again. It looks like I'm going to have a busy weekend and it will be productive with the help you've given me.

Comment: Now I just have to get my hand on one `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This is the document that I've been working on with my experience with the VisionFive 2 that I purchased. The software is kind of rough, GPU related functionality seems to be struggling, but the command line interface seems good.  [Setting Up a New VisionFive 2 RISC-V SBC](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5372327/Setting-Up-a-New-VisionFive-2-RISC-V-SBC).

Comment: Thank you sir, quite a nice write-up. Saved for when I run across the time and a VisionFive 2.

Comment: Good job getting it to work. WiringPi is a simple library. One note on PWM setup. (for motor control, especially fan control). It may seem counter-intuitive, but rarely do I need more than 128 or 256 increments (with a potentiometer, etc) to drive a duty-cycle from 0 - 100%. By selecting a smaller scale, you can make the PWM frequency higher (more switching on/off per-sec). This is critical. Human range of hearing tails off at about 20KHz. So to prevent audible motor or fan "whine" at less than 100% duty cycle, set the PWM frequency above 20KHz `:)`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I've update my article posted on CodeProject after discovering a storage limit issue and a solution. I now have Apache2 along with php and Postgre running on my device and did a simple web page. Am now able to use most of the 64 GB of the SD card. Been watching Linux device driver videos on YouTube and looking at code. Looks like there is a PWM backlight Linux driver I need to study. Looks like people are using `mmap()` for direct PWM device control from C. No standard, general PWM device driver. About to try a kernel build and see what smokes.

Comment: Likely `mmap()` is used to create a shared-memory block for the various processes communicating with the PWM. These little devices are springboards into all kinds of learning where there is already a "library for that" in the PC world. You certainly gain an appreciation for those that did all the work on the PC side to make life as easy as it is today. Imaging writing the X-windows library or the like...